# PayPal REST SDK for Ruby - non-global configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to use PayPal REST SDK in an application where there should be multiple API configurations - `client_id`s, `client_secret`s and `mode`s.

Essentially I would like a local API object like the one available in Python sdk:

```
# python

import paypalrestsdk
my_api = paypalrestsdk.Api({
   'mode': 'sandbox',
   'client_id': '...',
   'client_secret': '...'})

payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({...}, api=my_api)
```

whereas in Ruby it looks like:

```
PayPal::SDK.configure(
    :mode => "sandbox", # "sandbox" or "live"
    :client_id => "EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM",
    :client_secret => "EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM")
```

As far as I see this is currently impossible with the Ruby sdk.

Keeping in mind that I need just a small subset of what the SDK offers, my questions are:

1. Did I just miss the documentation concerning what I'm looking for?
2. If it really doesn't exist, am I better off writing my own "sdk" or should I adapt the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up forking the [rest api sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby) and altering a few, mostly static `find` methods, so now they have signature `def find(resource_id, new_api = nil)`.

If the new api parameter is present, it will be used, else default is used.

The fork is available [here](https://github.com/makkrnic/rest-api-sdk-ruby).

And the discussion is [here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby/pull/29).